# Variable lengths Differ error using nls function in R

Tags: r, nls, non-linear-regression, model-fitting

I am trying to fit the following data set using non-linear regression where v=rate, s=substrate conc and I=inhibitor conc

```
     v       s   I
1  0.030735  20  0
2  0.036813  30  0
3  0.043511  40  0
4  0.049580  60  0
5  0.053996  70  0
6  0.059996  80  0
7  0.064517 100  0
8  0.062283 120  0
9  0.069128 150  0
10 0.070157 180  0
11 0.010265  20  5
12 0.012665  30  5
13 0.016841  40  5
14 0.020061  60  5
15 0.023298  70  5
16 0.025832  80  5
17 0.026651 100  5
18 0.028431 120  5
19 0.030125 150  5
20 0.039977 180  5
21 0.009380  20  6
22 0.012413  30  6
23 0.016107  40  6
24 0.020513  60  6
25 0.021588  70  6
26 0.023146  80  6
27 0.026004 100  6
28 0.024654 120  6
29 0.026586 150  6
30 0.032169 180  6
31 0.008452  20  7
32 0.011441  30  7
33 0.015973  40  7
34 0.017618  60  7
35 0.019015  70  7
36 0.021235  80  7
37 0.024005 100  7
38 0.025089 120  7
39 0.025360 150  7
40 0.028029 180  7
41 0.007178  20  8
42 0.010141  30  8
43 0.012837  40  8
44 0.019752  60  8
45 0.019955  70  8
46 0.020838  80  8
47 0.021742 100  8
48 0.021748 120  8
49 0.024367 150  8
50 0.027416 180  8
51 0.008012  20 10
52 0.009509  30 10
53 0.012265  40 10
54 0.013161  60 10
55 0.014029  70 10
56 0.014719  80 10
57 0.018321 100 10
58 0.020250 120 10
59 0.021642 150 10
60 0.026193 180 10
```

To the following equation using the nls function, the initial values are very close to the actual values as I calculated them earlier and defined them.

```
mm.competitive.formula <- as.formula(v ~ ((Vmax*s)/ (Km*(1+(I/Ki)+s))))
mm.competitive <- nls(mm.competitive.formula, kinetics, start=list(Km=Ki.initial, Vmax=Vmax.initial, Ki=Ki.initial))
summary(mm.competitive)
```

However I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~v + s + I, data = list(rate = c(0.030735,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 's')
```

Because for each substrate concentration i have got 6 observations, one for each inhibitor conc. But for each inhibitor conc I have 10 substrate concentrations (at least from my readings on the error I think this is the case, I might be wrong).  I dont want to leave out any data, so i am unsure how to get around this issue.

```
structure(list(v = c(0.030735, 0.036813, 0.043511, 0.04958, 0.053996, 
0.059996, 0.064517, 0.062283, 0.069128, 0.070157, 0.010265, 0.012665, 
0.016841, 0.020061, 0.023298, 0.025832, 0.026651, 0.028431, 0.030125, 
0.039977, 0.00938, 0.012413, 0.016107, 0.020513, 0.021588, 0.023146, 
0.026004, 0.024654, 0.026586, 0.032169, 0.008452, 0.011441, 0.015973, 
0.017618, 0.019015, 0.021235, 0.024005, 0.025089, 0.02536, 0.028029, 
0.007178, 0.010141, 0.012837, 0.019752, 0.019955, 0.020838, 0.021742, 
0.021748, 0.024367, 0.027416, 0.008012, 0.009509, 0.012265, 0.013161, 
0.014029, 0.014719, 0.018321, 0.02025, 0.021642, 0.026193), s = c(20L, 
30L, 40L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 100L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 
60L, 70L, 80L, 100L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 60L, 70L, 
80L, 100L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 100L, 
120L, 150L, 180L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 100L, 120L, 150L, 
180L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 100L, 120L, 150L, 180L), 
    I = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Looks like you have a `rate` column name but not in your formula ? Could you paste `dput(kinetics)` please, so that we can reproduce.

Comment: Hi, I have added the output. The rate part is the v ~ at the start of the formula

Comment: Look at the error: `data = list(rate = c(0.030735......`. You used a dataframe with a `rate` column name instead of `v`.

Comment: The error I am getting is `<simpleError in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts): singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates>`.

Comment: In addition to the problems cited, the starting values are missing in the question and the model is not identifable since any values of Km and Vmax for which their ratio is the same will give the same model.